# Textview gets over ImageView back if text in textview is large Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created custom action bar which has ImageView of back button on left and center has textview which is title. I want title to be center. However if text is large it occupies every widhth available and overlaps Imageview as a result ImageView listener doesnt function and only TextView on click works any where on custom layout. Following is screenshot to explain you more.

[image: TextView if large overlaps Back ImageView and onClick of Image doesnt work]

If Textview is large i want textView to be center and move all characters to right for width available and then end with ...

Following is my code of XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#22c064"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help i want something like TextView center and it should look like asdasdasdasd ...

Comment: Used `LinearLayout` as per my answer.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: check this]Use just need to provide weight so which each view get percentage of total width.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/actionbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dip"
android:alpha="0.8"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.75"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:text="[2014-10-20 17:05:35 - NVOLV3] Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException [2014-10-20 17:05:35 - NVOLV3] Unknown error: java.lang.NullPointerException"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#22c064"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i update the answer now it's not overlapping any more

Comment: hi if text is small it is on left and not exactly center .. if large it should exactly behave as shown however if text is small it should be center with back on extreme left

Comment: just place android:gravity="center" in textview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rel_music"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="46dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingRight="3dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back_lay"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ib_back_music"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_music"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="title title title title title title title title title title "
        android:typeface="normal" />
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this code

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#22c064"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

to

```
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:drawablePadding="5dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
            android:textColor="#22c064"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: @vo12 then set ellipsize and maxLines 1

Comment: clean and build your project..then run

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backbutton"` from the `TextView`

I assume you should use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to align the text with the `ImageView`